# CSS: grayscale in IE (with percentage)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, webkit, grayscale

Is there a css-way to grayscaling a div with a properly percentage?
I can do this in non-IE browsers with webkit support:

```
-webkit-filter: grayscale(0.7); //e.g. 70%
```

But in IE I can only use a boolean function like this:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(grayscale=1); //with '1'
```

Can I find out a way (possibly a not-svg way), I can grayscaling an image with a percentage with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this link [**desaturate**](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/desaturate/)

**Browser Compatibility:**

Internet Explorer 5.5+, Opera 9.5+, Firefox 2+, WebKit Nightly

Comment: I believe the pixastic library only works on actual IMGs. It appears that the OP's question wants to desaturate an entire DIV.

Answer (score 1):

@A.K's suggestion looks good, although I couldn't immediately see how to do partial grey-scale...

For a CSS-only solution - you can achieve a similar effect by making whatever you want to grey-scale partially transparent and putting a background colour behind it, like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/R23LG/

Obviously you'd want to play around with the transparency settings etc. to get it how you want it.